# View pager is not refreshing after notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-viewpager, notifydatasetchanged

I spend much time but I can not get this to work. I have view pager in main activty. In this activity when user click on button start new activity where user can add new item to DB. After finish is this activity closed and user is back in main activity. Problem is my view pager dont want refresh when is onResume called. I debug it and all is working but list show old data. But when I swipe to 3rd tab and return back to firt now data are OK. So I read many here, try posssible, impossible but still not working. And second problem is if I swipe to second tab and then return to first then this listview is empty but i dont know why.

- pager offscreen limit is default  >> 1 page to each side is in RAM. Does any have any idea what is bad? Thx for time and help.

**Main activity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            selectedDayTabPosition = position;
            ((OnRefreshListener) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(position)).onRefresh(MainActivity.this, position);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(MainActivity.this));
    }
}

    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    refresh(selectedDayTabPosition);
}

  @Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

public void refresh(final int position) {
    subjectObjLinkedList.clear();
    subjectObjLinkedList = db.getAllSubjects(position, subjectObjLinkedList);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (lvAllSubjectsAtDay != null) {
                subjectsTableAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.d("refresh()", "notifyDataSetChanged");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**SectionsPagerAdapter**

```
      public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new PlaceholderFragment();
    }
```

**PlaceholderFragment**

```
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements OnRefreshListener {

    private TextView tvMainPageNoSubjectLabel;
    private TextView tvMainPageNoSubjectDescLabel;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        lvAllSubjectsAtDay = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvAllSubjectsAtDay);

        subjectsTableAdapter = new SubjectsTableAdapter(getActivity(), subjectObjLinkedList);
        lvAllSubjectsAtDay.setAdapter(subjectsTableAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh(Activity activity, int position) {
        refresh(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perform the update of listview in onResume of fragment

Comment: Try I get the same result list view show old data. I debug it list of items is ok, notify is caled but listview is still not updated.

Answer (score 0):

OK I find solution it is not perfect but is working. I create 7 separate fragments and in fragment class in onResume I call notifyDataChanged. Of course I delete all refresh methods from activity. I dont know why previous solution not refresh data but this is working.

```
        @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0: return new Fragments.FragmentTab1(db);
            case 1: return new Fragments.FragmentTab2(db);
            case 2: return new Fragments.FragmentTab3(db);
            case 3: return new Fragments.FragmentTab4(db);
            case 4: return new Fragments.FragmentTab5(db);
            case 5: return new Fragments.FragmentTab6(db);
            case 6: return new Fragments.FragmentTab7(db);
            default: return new Fragments.FragmentTab1(db);
        }
    }

 public static class FragmentTab1 extends Fragment {

    private TextView tvMainPageNoSubjectLabel;
    private TextView tvMainPageNoSubjectDescLabel;

    private SubjectsTableAdapter subjectsTableAdapter = null;
    private LinkedList<SubjectObj> objLinkedList = new LinkedList<>();
    private MySQLiteHelper db = null;

    public FragmentTab1(MySQLiteHelper db){
        this.db = db;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        ListView lvAllSubjectsAtDay = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvAllSubjectsAtDay);
        tvMainPageNoSubjectLabel = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvMainPageNoSubjectLabel);
        tvMainPageNoSubjectDescLabel = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvMainPageNoSubjectDescLabel);

        lvAllSubjectsAtDay.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ConfigSubjectActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("idSelectedSubject", parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position));
                getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
                return true;
            }
        });

        subjectsTableAdapter = new SubjectsTableAdapter(getActivity(), objLinkedList);
        lvAllSubjectsAtDay.setAdapter(subjectsTableAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        objLinkedList.clear();
        objLinkedList = db.getAllSubjects(0, objLinkedList);
        subjectsTableAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        hideDefaultLabels();
    }

    private void hideDefaultLabels() {
        if (objLinkedList.size() > 0) {
            tvMainPageNoSubjectLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvMainPageNoSubjectDescLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            tvMainPageNoSubjectLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvMainPageNoSubjectDescLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```